# Quadratic numer fields with discriminant $d_6$

Tags: number-theory

Let $K$ be a quadratic number field with discriminant $d_k$.

Let $O_K = \mathbb Z [ \frac{d_K+ \sqrt{d_K}}{2} ]$

Is $(3+2 \sqrt{6}) / (1- \sqrt{6}) \in O_6$ ?

Comment: try to multiply and divide by $1+\sqrt{6}$ and see what happens

Comment: Sorry the stupid question, but what do I have to divide/multiply by what?

Comment: $\frac{3+2\sqrt{6}}{1-\sqrt{6}}=\frac{3+2\sqrt{6}}{1-\sqrt{6}}\cdot \frac{1+\sqrt{6}}{1+\sqrt{6}}$. Now do the algebra!

Comment: @Ferra Ok, did it. It results $-3-\sqrt{6}$, with minimal polynomial $x^2+6x+3$. Is this correct? So we are in $O_6$, right?